# Missing Jar Files for HelloGlobe (JogAmp)

Tags: jar, jogl

I am trying to run the following [example](https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle/blob/master/src/main/java/gl4/HelloGlobe.java).

I get errors for the following lines

```
import framework.Semantic;
import glm.mat.Mat4x4;
import glm.vec._2.Vec2;
import glm.vec._3.Vec3;
import uno.debug.GlDebugOutput;
import uno.glsl.Program;

...

import static glm.GlmKt.glm;
import static uno.buffer.UtilKt.destroyBuffer;
import static uno.buffer.UtilKt.destroyBuffers;
```

It seems that I am missing some more jar files even though I successfully imported jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar

I tried searching [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) but did not find the jars I was looking for. I am not using maven.

Comment: The problem doesn't come from JOGL, you can get the latest single JogAmp fat JAR here: https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20210111/fat/ framework.Semantic is here: https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle/blob/master/src/main/java/framework/Semantic.java Maybe this comment helps for other dependencies: https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle/issues/4#issuecomment-464132651 Why not using the official JogAmp examples instead? https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Jogl_Tutorial

Comment: By the way, rather contact JogAmp contributors and maintainers on our official forum: https://forum.jogamp.org

Comment: I've just updated the wiki: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle_and_Texture Maybe using a similar example in pure Java as I suggest would be easier.